# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. > java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I get the following error when i try to build release build. I am using android studio 2.3 . I have added my gradle and proguard rules files below and i ma using mac with mac os X

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file '/Users/username/Documents/Android Projects/Project Name/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar'.
```

proguard rules file

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn com.razorpay.**
-keep class com.razorpay.** {*;}

-optimizations !method/inlining/*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public void onPayment*(...);
}

-keep @interface butterknife.*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @butterknife.On* <methods>;
}

-keep class **$$ViewInjector {
    public static void inject(...);
    public static void reset(...);
}

-keep class **$$ViewBinder {
    public static void bind(...);
    public static void unbind(...);
}



-keep class com.google.common.** {*;}


-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
```

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.projectname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.greenfrvr:hashtag-view:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.leaking.slideswitch:slideswitch:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/leaking/maven'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I assume you have tried `clean project` and `build`, right?

Comment: post your project level gradle file too

Comment: yes I have tried that @azizbekian

Comment: @ArunElectra added project gradle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is referenced [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221057) which occurs in project including non ASCII class names. The issue will be addressed from version 2.4 of gradle Android plugin (not yet released at this time).

An alternative is to downgrade to 2.2.3 :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Comment: I was just going to move to v2.2.3 of Android Studio, this saved me. Thanks alot.

Comment: These non-ascii chars are coming from Razorpay dependencies. If you check their code, they're using obfuscation that uses non-ascii chars. Seems they're taking great pains to make deciphering their SDK harder XD

Comment: Is there a way to enable instant run in this case??

Answer (score 0):

For me this error happened when I was building project on Windows, where write access was given only to admin users, and Android studio was launched in a regular mode (not administrator mode). When I launched Android studio with "Run as administrator", write access was available and .apk was generated successfully.